# Change non-latin character to latin character in string

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

I'm trying to match by regex in Ruby or in Javascript a string that contains non english characters.

So is there a way to replace the string "täglichen" with the string "taglichen" ?
I know that i can replace non english characters by options like:

```
/(?i)t[aä]glichen/
```

But for this i need dictionary of possible characters and set all of them in searched word. Maybe there is a more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: No, there is not. Even inline modifiers are not supported (Chrome only). You may want to have a look at [xregexp](http://xregexp.com) lib.

Comment: Are you able to [`normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) the string? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think i will go with normalize input string and compare always with normalized string in database. I'm trying to achieve search if you search for Täglichen then i want to find in database Taglichen (in database i have without special character). Easiest solution will compare always normalized strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a legit solution for modern ruby, using [`String#unicode_normalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize)

```
"täglichen".unicode_normalize(:nfd).
            codepoints.
            reject(&128.method(:<)).
            pack('U*')
#⇒ "taglichen"
```

To match:

```
"täglichen".unicode_normalize(:nfc) =~ /t[aä]glichen/i
#⇒ 0
```

The normalization is needed because umlaut might be either a single codepoint `228` or a combined diacritics `[97, 776]`. Check this (try to copy-paste into your REPL):

```
"ä" == "ä"
#⇒ false
```

Comment: thx, i know how to normalize string, i was thinking is it possible to ask for Taglichen by täglichen without normalization with some regex.

Comment: You have to either normalize it upfront or to match both `228` _and_ `[97, 776]`. I enter umlauts in every day (pun intented) but I don’t have it on keyboard and I believe you still want to match combined diacritics as well.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is slugify your strings before matching (https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify)

```
Input: "Ich heiße Fred"
Output: "ich-heisse-fred"
```

If you don't like the `-` characters as separators you can change that, as stated by the docs